# Import bibliography to lyx

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx

I have already created a BibTex generated bibliography in LyX. However, when I work on another computer, there is an error because the system doesn't find the BibTex files. Is there a way to import all files to the document without writing them manually? The problem is that I have already written citations and there can be bugs in the document.

Comment: If the path to the .bib file is relative, as long as you preserve the directory structure on the different computer, it should work. Perhaps double-check that the path to the .bib file is relative.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "relative"?

Comment: An absolute path is something like /a/b/c/myfile.bib. A relative path is something like "myfile.bib" (in the same directory as the .lyx file) or "lit/myfile.bib". Here the paths are "relative" to the .lyx file.